# How to read label data if read data from MemoryData in caffe

Tags: caffe

This is my data layer of net.prototxt:

```
layer {
    name: "csv"
    type: "MemoryData"
    top: "data"
    top: "label"
    include {
        phase: TRAIN
    }
    memory_data_param {
        batch_size: 10
        channels: 1
        width: 14
        height: 1
    }
}
```

I find the function

```
MemoryDataLayer<Dtype>::Reset(Dtype* data, Dtype* labels, int n)
```

but I don't know where should I add this function to?

Now I want to know where
 is the label data from? Because I only see label key word in Datum struct.

Answer (score 0):

I always use MemoryData layer when I train a network through pycaffe module.Like this

```
solver = caffe.SGDSolver(solver_file)

X = np.zeros((batch_size, 3, im_height, im_width), dtype = np.float32)
Y = np.zeros((batch_size, ), dtype = np.float32)
# put processed images into X, put labels into Y

solver.net.set_input_arrays(X,Y)
```

you can refer caffe_root/python/caffe/pycaffe.py and _caffe.cpp for detail